# html calender(datepicker) with an addable event

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

Hi I am looking to allow uses to add events into a calender(using date-picker at the moment) by entering data into text-boxes then clicking on a date on the calender then hitting submit. I want events to be highlighted and when a date is clicked on (with an event on it) the event pops up with the information.

Tried to search but I did not have any luck.

Thank you

EDIT:  Changed a bit of the code so it compiled properly

I would also like to simply reference the date that is selected so that I may use it to record the data. To use this program simply type in your values than hit refresh and the new values will be loaded into the 13th of may.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery &amp; jQueryUI Base - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.7/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">





      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.highlight > a {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_inset-hard_55_ffeb80_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% bottom #FFEB80;
    color: #363636;
    border: 1px solid #FFDE2E;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var equip = document.getElementById('equipment').value;
var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
var surface = document.getElementById('surface').value;
var orderNumber = document.getElementById('orderNumber').value;
var responsible = document.getElementById('responsible').value;
var events = [ 
    { Title: "Equipment: " + equip + "\nSize: " + size, Date: new Date("05/13/2013") }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("02/25/2011") }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2011") }
];



$("div").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var result = [true, '', null];
        var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

        while (i < events.length && !event) {
            date = events[i].Date;

            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                event = events[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (event) {
            alert(event.Title);
        }
    }
});
});//]]>
addLow()

</script>


</head>
<body>
Equipment: <input type='text' id='equipment' /> <br />
Size: <input type='text' id='size' /> <br />
Required on Surface: <input type='radio' id='surface' /> <br />
Work Order Number: <input type='text' id='orderNumber' /> <br />
Responsible: <input type='text' id='responsible' /> <br />
  <div></div>
<button type="button" onclick="addLow()">Add Lowering Event</button><br>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: What kind of date-picker are you using? Could you link the reference?

Comment: @Niels - Since the OP is including jQuery UI I'd say it's safe to assume that it's the jQuery UI datepicker.

Comment: He didnt had any html yet when i posted the message.

Comment: Any tips would be great too,  I haven't done html for 5 years and am extremely rusty.  How do I reference the selected date in the array submission.